# Crear XML con estructura especifica

Tags: c#, xml, xdocument

necesito generar un xml con una estructura un tanto complicada

Primer bloque:

```
<rule id="Main">
    <item>
      YO <ruleref uri="#Nombre" />
      CON NUMERO DE TELEFONO CELULAR<ruleref uri="#Numero" />
      EXPRESO MI VOLUNTAD<ruleref uri="#Voluntad" />
      MI CUENTA INDIVIDUAL<ruleref uri="#Tramite" />
      Y HAGO ENTREGA<ruleref uri="#Recibe" />
      AL AGENTE PROMOTOR<ruleref uri="#Agente" />
      CON NUMERO<ruleref uri="#Numero1" />
      QUIEN ME PROPORCIONO<ruleref uri="#Propociono" />
      DE LAS IMPLICACIONES<ruleref uri="#Implicaciones" /></item>
  </rule>
  <rule id="Nombre" scope="public">
    <one-of>
      <item>GERARDO TOLEDO SANCHEZ</item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>
```

Segundo bloque:

```
<rule id="Numero" scope="public">
    <one-of>
      <item>5566778899</item>
    </one-of>   </rule>   <rule id="Voluntad" scope="public">
    <one-of>
      <item>DE TRANSPASAR</item>
    </one-of>   </rule>
```

Con el segundo bloque no tengo problema para generarlo:

> ```
> XDocument miXML = XDocument.Load(pathDataFile); //Cargamos
>             miXML.Root.Add(   //Obtiene la raiz del documento (Empleados)                         
>              new XElement("rule",
>              new XAttribute("id", "Numero"),
>              new XAttribute("scope", "public"),
>              new XElement("one-of", new XElement("item", "5566778899"))
>                           ));
>             miXML.Save(pathDataFile);
> ```

Pero simplemente no puedo hacer que el primer bloque se genere, he intentado asignándole un nuevo element dentro del texto pero no se genera

Tendrán alguna idea de como generar algo similar?? Toda la ayuda es bien recibida

Comment: ese xml no esta bien formado.. la propiedad texto de un item no puede contener otros elementos de xml asi como asi...

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, ese xml es inválido. Antes de tratar de generarlo, prueba en algun sitio de validación xml si es correcto, por ejemplo en https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: @gbianchi los elementos de un documento XML pueden contener otros elementos XML e incluso texto, es lo que se conoce como **contenido mixto**.

Comment: Estoy tratando de crear un grammar para SpeechRecognition el XML que puse viene directamente de Microsoft les dejo la liga para que lo validen https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.speech.recognition.grammar(v=vs.110).aspx si se puede tener un XML con las caracteristicas antes descritas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos si te sirve el siguiente ejemplo. Se crea un nodo con contenido mixto:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlMixedContent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //salida del resultado por la consola
            XmlTextWriter writer = null;
            writer = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);

            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            //creación de un elemento 
            writer.WriteStartElement("libro");

            //elemento con contenido mixto
            writer.WriteStartElement("titulo");
            writer.WriteString("El ingenioso hidalgo ");
            writer.WriteStartElement("b");
            writer.WriteString("Don Quijote de la Mancha");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            //cierre del elemento libro
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.Close();

            Console.Read();
        }           }
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución es:

```
<libro>
    <titulo>El ingenioso hidalgo <b>Don Quijote de la Mancha</b></titulo>
</libro>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, aun que ocupe otra alternativa funciona correctamente tu ejemplo, te agradezco mucho tu tiempo y el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

El fichero XML que propones (y me atengo a tu primer y segundo bloque)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rule id="Main" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\TMP\XML\AAAAA.xsd">
    <item>
      YO <ruleref uri="#Nombre"/>
      CON NUMERO DE TELEFONO CELULAR<ruleref uri="#Numero"/>
      EXPRESO MI VOLUNTAD<ruleref uri="#Voluntad"/>
      MI CUENTA INDIVIDUAL<ruleref uri="#Tramite"/>
      Y HAGO ENTREGA<ruleref uri="#Recibe"/>
      AL AGENTE PROMOTOR<ruleref uri="#Agente"/>
      CON NUMERO<ruleref uri="#Numero1"/>
      QUIEN ME PROPORCIONO<ruleref uri="#Propociono"/>
      DE LAS IMPLICACIONES<ruleref uri="#Implicaciones"/>
    </item>
    <rule id="Nombre" scope="public">
        <one-of>
            <item>GERARDO TOLEDO SANCHEZ</item>
        </one-of>
    </rule>
</rule>
```

está bien formado y es válido, siempre que se adapte a un esquema como:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="item">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="ruleref"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="one-of">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="item"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="rule">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="rule" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="one-of" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Main"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="Nombre"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="scope">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="public"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ruleref">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="uri" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Agente"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Implicaciones"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Nombre"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Numero"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Numero1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Propociono"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Recibe"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Tramite"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="#Voluntad"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Otra cosa es que sea un poco enrevesado, de ahí tu problema para crearlo vía programación. Tu mismo dices que el segundo bloque lo generas sin problema.
¿Por qué no pensáis un poco como mejorar el primer bloque y hacerlo, digamos, más estilo XML?

Comment: El problema aquí es que estoy generando un grammar dinámico para speech recognition y me lo pide exactamente con la estructura y forma que lo coloque ya que si no se introduce así ya no se puede generar el grammar, esto es para Reconocimiento de Voz

Comment: @JlPrieto como puedo hacer para poder hacer esto : xs: simpleType concatenar el nombre del root principal que es XS Y concatenado el nombre del nodo

Comment: Pones un ejemplo